# How to remove a character from the end of a string

Tags: php, string

I have the following string: 
`$string = "username, email, status, password,"`
edit: How do I remove the last occurance of the `,` character from the string?

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = trim($string,",");
```

That would work. [`trim()` on php.net](http://php.net/trim)

Comment: Should use `rtrim` in case he needs to keep leading commas.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the last character from `$string`, you can use this:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
```

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

`$string = substr($string, 0, -1);`